Dart - Serializing and deserializing custom object into and from JSON
I'm looking for some help with an issue I've been trying to solve for the past couple of days...
My School object contains a list of LateBus objects. On app launch, the list of school objects is saved and loaded via SharedPreferences. Something is wrong with the way I'm encoding the decoding my School and/or LateBus objects that is preventing my app from operating correctly.
Can anyone spot why the serialization/deserialization isn't working? Thanks so much.
class School implements Comparable<School> {
  final String name;
  final List<String> aliases;
  bool isFavorite;

  //* for late status only *//
  List<LateBus> lateBuses;

...

  School.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'] as String,
        aliases = List<String>.from(json['aliases']),
        isFavorite = json['isFavorite'] as bool,
        lateBuses = (jsonDecode(json['lateBuses']) as List)
            .map((e) => LateBus.fromJson(e))
            .toList();

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'name': name,
        'aliases': aliases,
        'isFavorite': isFavorite,
        'lateBuses': jsonEncode(lateBuses),
      };
}




class LateBus {
...
LateBus.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : appliesTo = json['AppliesTo'] as String,
        routeRun = json['RouteRun'] as String,
        zone = json['Zone'] as Null,
        operator = json['Operator'] as String,
        action = json['Action'] as String,
        affectsSchools = json['AffectsSchools'] as String,
        transfersSchools = json['TransfersSchools'] as String,
        comment = json['Comment'] as String,
        isCreateTimeVisible = json['IsCreateTimeVisible'] as bool,
        createTime = json['CreateTime'] as String,
        createTimeDisplay = json['CreateTimeDisplay'] as String;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'appliesTo': appliesTo,
        'routeRun': routeRun,
        'zone': zone,
        'operator': operator,
        'action': action,
        'affectsSchools': affectsSchools,
        'transfersSchools': transfersSchools,
        'comment': comment,
        'isCreateTimeVisible': isCreateTimeVisible,
        'createTime': createTime,
        'createTimeDisplay': createTimeDisplay,
      };
}


Can you provide an example JSON data?

Also include any error messages you are getting.

In lateBuses = (jsonDecode(json['lateBuses']) as List), do you really need to decode json['lateBuses'] again?

Can you please add a try-catch block where you get errors for encoding and decoding? As well as print Exception e and Stack trace s. So, you will get more idea about your error or mistake.

It's weird, but the code doesn't throw an exception - it just freezes there. This is the problematic statement:
    _schools = List<School>.from(
    jsonDecode(prefJson).map((data) => School.fromJson(data)))
    ..sort();

